# Testing RailsAdmin mounted in Rails 4 app with Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest, rails-admin

In a Rails 4 app with Minitest, I would like to do some functional testing of RailsAdmin which I mounted. I really don't know where to start.

Should I make RailsAdminControllerTest classes per model?

I also created custom actions for RailsAdmin so I hope this helps me test this code too.

I'm quite new with TDD. Is there an demo app or tutorial for testing RailsAdmin with MiniTest?

Comment: For now I'm using integration tests to check functionality of my my custom actions in the RailsAdmin backend. Here is how I did it: https://gist.github.com/mipmip/7fcd58789ea9ff7f7a83